# Css Form don't fit the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, css

In all my pages my content fit to the body:[image]

But where i have forms they go over the footer and body don't resize:
[image]

Where is the problem?

Comment: And how to resolve it is there any proprety to solve this?

Comment: Give your container a CSS rule `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form probably contains a lot of floated elements, so you might want add this to your `<form>` CSS:

```
form {
    ...

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced something similar this week. 
Try using

```
<div style="clear:both"/>
```

to encapsulate your content within your page.

```
<div id="mainDiv">
content 
 <div style="clear:both"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue is clearly with floated elements in the form. You can fix it using the micro clearfix by Nicolas Gallagher, currently the "best practice" for the issue

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Don't use overflow: hidden; as it might give you trouble if you want any element to overflow the form. (eg. select).
Also, tables are not a good idea for the layout, and empty divs to clear are not necessary.